# Why doesn't Integer.parseInt work on a substring?

Tags: java, android

This conversion is not working, I am getting an exception,
not sure why

```
    String str = "Draw: 1";
    int draw = 0;
    String temp;
    temp = str.substring(5,7);
    draw= Integer.parseInt(temp);
    System.out.println(draw);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're trying to parse " 1", notice the space. Adding a trim() should solve it.

`temp = str.substring(5,7).trim();`